# Woocommerce E-Mail Subject Order_Date Not Translated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using **Woocommerce Version 2.6.14** (Update not a possibility for other reasons).

Problem is `{order_date}` variable in E-mail subject isn't translated on different system e-mail templates. Here is an example.

A user orders a product, the system sends first mail to a user which is created by.

```
woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-on-hold-order.php
```

The Subject Section is as follows:

[image]

And the E-Mail subject user receives (`{order_date}` translated, no problem):

> **Nisan 25**, 2018 tarihli tisort.ist siparişiniz bize ulaştı.

Then I change the order's status to "processing" system sends another e-mail to a user using the following template.

```
woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-processing-order.php
```

The Subject Section is as follows:

[image]

And E-Mail subject user receives is (`{order_date}` still in english ):

> **April 25**, 2018 tarihli tisort.ist siparişiniz işleniyor.

I couldn't find any differences in templates or other places. How can I debug this?

Comment: I think the problem is in the translation files. Try checking `woocommerce/i18n/languages/` and look for your language file. Look for `customer-processing-order.php` inside the language file. Also look for `customer-on-hold-order.php` to compare.